# Is there a way to see who created an event in a shared iCal calendar?

Tags: ical, calendar

I'm using iCal to share numerous calendars with my wife.  We're using iCloud to sync them.

On occasion, I need to know which of us put an appointment on the calendar, but can't remember.

I know that somewhere, the system is capturing the creator, because notifications tells me that "[EVENT] has been added to the Calendar by [User]."

But I can't find a way to retrieve that user info from the appointment itself.  "Get info" would often be source of this kind of data in OSX, but in iCal, it's just the same info as you see in the full appointment view.

Is there somewhere else I can find this?

Answer (score 1):

In Calendar (on Mountain Lion), if you right click on the event to view the details, one of the invitees is marked as "(organizer)"

Comment: I'm not seeing that.  I tried right-clicking in all the views (list, day, week...) and I just get a context menu with "Get Info", "Calendar", "Delete", etc.   There is no invitees field.  I can see invitees by double clicking, but that's no help - there are none.

Comment: Oops - meant double click (not right click)